# Wordpress TinyMCD download

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, tinymce

Anyone know of a place where I can download the TinyMCE and image uploader that wordpress uses or at the very least something similar?

Answer (score 2):

you can download pluginusing this url.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/